# how to set focus to autocomplete combobox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

At first accept my apology for bad English.
I have 2 questions.

1. I have two HTML elements on a page: input text, select option (autocomplete combo box).  I want to focus on select option when I press enter on input text. How can I set focus to combo box?
2. I have 2 elements like these.

   ```
   <input type="text" id="chosegender" />
   <select id="gender">     
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="m">male</option>
     <option value="f">female</option>
   </select>
   ```

I want to select male when I press <kbd>f</kbd> on input tag and select `m` when I press <kbd>m</kbd> on input tag.

I'd appreciate you if you can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: It is best if you split up your 2 questions in to two separate posts, instead of combining them in to 1 here.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, to transfer on the enter key you can use the following jquery code:

```
$('#chosegender').on('keypress', function(e) { 
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('#gender').focus();
    } 
    return true;
});
```

I wasn't too sure what the actual goal was on the second part but I put together a snippet that should help:

```
$('#gender').on('keypress', function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 109: // m
        case 77:  // M
            $('#gender').val('f');
            break;
        case 102: // f
        case 70:  // F
            $('#gender').val('m');
            break;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I attached an event listener on the keypress event, you can use it on the keydown or keyup to access it earlier.  On the second I returned false to in part cancel the bubble, but on some cases you might need to use the `preventDefault()` event method to prevent the browser from capturing the key.  I've used this to prevent the default behavior of the tab key.